# Keras find index by vectors - Reverse embedding layer

Tags: keras, reverse, embedding

Simple question.
When using Embedding layer from keras, it would go like this

```
[index, index, index,...,index] -> [[vec], [vec], [vec]...,[vec]]
```

where index is some integer number and vec is vector.

Now suppose if I have vectors. How can I get index from these vectors? Does Keras support using it in FC network Model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reverse word embeddings in keras - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773660/reverse-word-embeddings-in-keras-python)

Comment: Thanks. I found similar questions as well... should I delete the question then? I don't know the rule well...

Comment: Judge for yourself :) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355459/should-i-delete-duplicate-questions